# Get Specific Tags from WebPage

Tags: html, powershell

I have been trying for hours to use PowerShell (and numerous StackOverflow threads/Google articles) - but failed to make this work.

I have this PowerShell Script:

```bsh
$URI = "http://example.html"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
```

Which returns the HTML below. 
I am just trying to get the "In" and "Out" values which appears under "Average max 5 min values for `Daily' Graph (5 Minute interval): - and not the`weekly' values, which have almost identical tags.

```html
<!-- End Head -->
<!-- Begin `Daily' Graph (5 Minute --><div class="graph">
        <h2>`Daily' Graph (5 Minute Average)</h2>
        <img src="aklsr2_gi0_1-day.png" title="day" alt="day" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th scope="col">Max</th>
                <th scope="col">Average</th>
                <th scope="col">Current</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="in">
                <th scope="row">In</th>
                <td>9939.4 kb/s (99.4%)</td>
                <td>1908.7 kb/s (19.1%) </td>
                <td>80.8 kb/s (0.8%) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="out">
                <th scope="row">Out</th>
                <td>9682.3 kb/s (96.8%) </td>
                <td>344.1 kb/s (3.4%) </td>
                <td>83.8 kb/s (0.8%) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Average max 5 min values for `Daily' Graph (5 Minute interval):
                    <span class="in">In</span> 2264.1 kb/s (22.6%)/
                    <span class="out">Out</span> 451.0 kb/s (4.5%)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- End `Daily' Graph (5 Minute -->

<!-- Begin `Weekly' Graph (30 Minute -->
    <div class="graph">
        <h2>`Weekly' Graph (30 Minute Average)</h2>
        <img src="aklsr2_gi0_1-week.png" title="week" alt="week" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th scope="col">Max</th>
                <th scope="col">Average</th>
                <th scope="col">Current</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="in">
                <th scope="row">In</th>
                <td>9939.4 kb/s (99.4%)</td>
                <td>1273.3 kb/s (12.7%) </td>
                <td>98.8 kb/s (1.0%) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="out">
                <th scope="row">Out</th>
                <td>9775.1 kb/s (97.8%) </td>
                <td>249.9 kb/s (2.5%) </td>
                <td>61.6 kb/s (0.6%) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Average max 5 min values for `Weekly' Graph (30 Minute interval):
                    <span class="in">In</span> 2236.6 kb/s (22.4%)/
                    <span class="out">Out</span> 593.8 kb/s (5.9%)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- End `Weekly' Graph (30 Minute -->
```

Comment: `$HTML.ParsedHtml`?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I have tried that. I can get the ParsedHTML back, but how do I effectively say 
    "Select <span class = "out">.outerHTML where <h2> = `Daily' Graph (5 Minute Average)</h2> 

in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -match comparison operator. -match will match only the first occurrence, and since the values are the first ones in the HTML output, it will give you the values you need. 
You can do something like this:

```
$regexes = @('<span class="in">In<\/span> (.*)/', '<span class="out">Out</span> (.*)')

$regexes | ForEach-Object {
    $htmlText -match $_ 
    $Matches[1]
}
```